# Bone broth ruined because I didn’t fully cool down before I put in the fridge?

Tags: food-safety

I made a great bone broth recipe in slow cooker. Well I strained it and put in an air tight container. It wasn’t cooled to much. So is it ruined? Can I reheat to a certain temperature to make sure there aren’t any bad bacteria?